# Sharing data between applications from different publishers

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I tried to search for this particular case but didn't find anything yet. Sharing data between two applications is possible with `ContentProvider` and you can set `protectionLevel` to `signature`, so applications with that signature can access the data (same publisher).

But what if the scenario is following:

- Developer A and B publishes application.
- Me, A and B decide to do some co-work together. I am to provide my own application, but I need to access both A and B private information.

Is this possible? A and B would need to grant my application to access their let's say `ContentProvider`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `protectionLevel` to `signature` will only allow to access data between applications signed with the same key (in this case A, B and you should agree on using the same key to sign your published applications).

If this is not the case, then A and B should export their `ContentProvider` and (optionally) provide permissions to read/write data. If they define permissions, then your client application should specify this permission in the manifest.

References:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html

Comment: Doing that way, is any application also possible to get A and B ContentProvider data?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that if A and B export their ContentProvider then any application can access this data. If they define permissions, then  is up to the user to accept them when installing the client application.

Comment: So there is no way to grant access to only specific application to get some private data without having to communicate with servers?